# When i export my array, i can only list the last item of my array - React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Currently i'm making a word test application. I found a database and added all items in my array.

Here is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import Navigator from './routes/menuStack';

export const N5Words = [];

export default function App(){

  var RNFS = require('react-native-fs');

  RNFS.readFileAssets('N5.txt', 'utf8')
  .then((contents) => {

    let allWords = contents.split('\n');
    let word = { key: 0, japanese: 'japanese', kana: 'kana', turkish: 'turkish' }

    for (var i = 0; i < allWords.length; i++){

      let splittedRow = allWords[i].split('\t');

      word.key = i;
      word.japanese = splittedRow[0].toString();
      word.kana = splittedRow[1].toString();
      word.turkish = splittedRow[2].toString();

      N5Words.push(word);

    }

  })
  
  return(
    <Navigator/>
  );
}
```

I want to use this array in another scripts.
So, i write the code below, on the other script:

```
import React from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, View, Text, Button, ScrollView} from 'react-native';
import { globalStyles } from '../styles/global';
import { N5Words } from '../App';

export default function KelimeTesti({ navigation }){

    return (
        <View style={globalStyles.container}>

        <Text style={globalStyles.smallText}>You're in Kelime Testi</Text>
        
        <ScrollView>
        { N5Words.map((word) => {
            return (
                <View key={word.key}>
                    <Text style={globalStyles.smallText}>{word.japanese}</Text>
                </View>
            )
        })}
        </ScrollView>

        </View>
    )
}
```

But it's not working. When i export the array and use that array in another script, only the last item of my script is listed.

[Output of the Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xzN2g.png)

There is no problem with the first code. I checked the items in console and it's reading all the words properly and they have unique id's which is from 0 to 668.

I get this error 668 times (for every word):

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3UfYy.png)

And that's how my database looks like :

```
会う  あう  to meet
青   あお  blue
青い  あおい blue
赤   あか  red
赤い  あかい red
明い  あかるい    bright
秋   あき  autumn
開く  あく  to open,to become open
開ける あける to open
上げる あげる to give
朝   あさ  morning
```

Comment: avoid using a constant to communicate things - especially things that are populated async

Comment: I'm newbie in react native, thanks. Is that why the problem occurs? I'll change it and try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. I'm writing this for anyone who deals with this problem.
Instead exporting and importing the database array, i sent it with navigation parameter.
And i get the array with getParam method. Then it worked.

While listing the array, i used both map() function and flat list. I wasn't able to list the items because i was getting an error which is "undefined is not an object".
I also solved that problem. I was using a variable called "word" as in my question. I changed it into "item" and that's it. I think we can't use another variable name except "item" while listing array.